# jtwitter permission issue Android

Tags: android, permissions, oauth, jtwitter

I'm tryin to tweet a simple post from my Android application. I followed a ([tutorial](http://66.135.38.140/sites/devcommunity/android-post-status-twitter-using-jtwitter-example) and the login works fine. Now when I try to tweet my Logcat says I don't have the rights to post something. I read something about OAuthProvider and follow a couple tutorials of that but without succes. Anyone got an idea?

Thanks

Code:
Twitter jtwit = new Twitter(user_name, pswd);
jtwit.setStatus("test");

Log:
03-29 13:52:02.724: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1341): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-29 13:52:02.724: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1341): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{Adforce.files/Adforce.files.twitterConnection}: winterwell.jtwitter.TwitterException$UpdateToOAuth: You need to switch to OAuth. Twitter no longer support basic authentication.

Comment: for tweet a message we want some credentials

Answer (score 0):

Your exception says itself:

> You need to switch to OAuth. Twitter no longer support basic authentication.

I suppose twitter has now stopped support for basic authentication and you might look at [Twitter OAuth](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html)

Comment: I know that I have to use OAuth. But I was wondering if it was possible with the jtweet (I know it is possible, but can't figure out how..). I've already tried the twitter4j but got problems with that. Going to try again anyway. Thanks for your reaction!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a OAuthSignpostClient, then get the user to authenticate it, and then use

Twitter jtwit = new Twitter(userName, myOAuthClient);